# php display image onlick and open new window

Tags: php

Need some help on php, i am able to display the images inside a table but not sure how to open a new window when clicked on the displayed images $field5name, can anyone share and guide me, thanks.

```
 echo '<tr> 
              <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
           <td><img src='.$field5name.' height="100" width="100"></td> 
                      </tr>';
```

Comment: What should happen when you open a new window?

Comment: Hi. It will open a new window to see the bigger image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<tr> 
    <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
    <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
    <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
    <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
    <td>
        <a href = "{$field5name}" target = "_blank">
            <img src="{$field5name}" height="100" width="100">
        </a>    
    </td> 
</tr>';
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I can put a ahref linkk now on the image, when i clicked the image it open a new window but wrong url. $field4name is the image name i get it from mysql. eg. 123.jpeg, any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i got it working, below is the code, thank you.

```
echo '<tr> 
              <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
           <td><a href = '.$field5name.' target = "_blank"><img src='.$field5name.' height="100" width="100"></td> 
                      </tr>';
```

Comment: Hi i got one request, how to display default image if there is no images record in mysql database, eg. NULL record, can it be done?